# Бесконечность double 1.#INF?

Tags: c++, double

1. Почему в примере сравнение переменной ind с самой собой даёт отрицательный результат?
2. Для проверки на бесконечность можно ли использовать эту конструкцию `if(ind != ind)`?
3. Что из себя представляет это значение в памяти, оно хранится как число или как что, ведь сравнивать его невозможно?
4. Переменная ind больше числа 5.4, меньше 5.4 или равна 5.4?

   ```
   double zero = 0.0;

   double pinf = 1 / zero;
   double minf = -pinf;
   double ind = pinf - pinf; 

   std::cout << "\nind=" << ind; //-1.#IND

   if(ind == std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity())
   {
   std::cout << "\n\nинфинити:" << ind;
   }

   if(ind == -std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity())
   {
   std::cout << "\n\nинфинити2:" << ind;
   }

   if(ind != ind)
   {
   std::cout << "\n\nинфинити3:" << ind;
   }
   ```

Comment: > Что из себя представляет это значение в памяти?

ближайший гугл, IEEE 754

> Infinity
The values +infinity and -infinity are denoted with an exponent of all 1s and a fraction of all 0s. The sign bit distinguishes between negative infinity and positive infinity. Being able to denote infinity as a specific value is useful because it allows operations to continue past overflow situations. Operations with infinite values are well defined in IEEE floating point.

Comment: Жаль нельзя минус поставить за коммент. На русский переводите, я же не на англ. форуме вопрос задаю. Хочется прочитать коммент на русском, а не ссылку на стандарт.

Comment: @manking ужасно. Вроде и ответ принес, но нет - недостаточно постарался, все-таки минус.

Из чего состоит double/float? Из знака (1 бит), экспоненты (11/8 бит) и мантиссы (52/23 бит). Для значений "бесконечность" зарезервированы состояния, в которых все биты экспоненты выставлены в 1, а все биты мантиссы - в ноль.

вики для стопроцентности https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: @Etki 
Вот так лучше.
А как проверить на бесконечность, используя конструкции языка? Это возможно или нет?

Comment: @manking

c++11: [isinf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/isinf/)  
с++ < c++11: [boost isinf](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/fpclass.html)  
в языке по-прежнему не понимаю и половины, нашел сами знаете где.

Comment: @manking, без умения хотя бы читать и понимать английский Вам в сфере IT ничего не светит.

Comment: @avp
Я и так этим чтением постоянно занимаюсь. Хочется то, чтобы был человеческий ответ, а не цитата из стандартов, форумы для этого существуют. В других науках люди постоянно контактируют по мелочам, а здесь только и делай, что читай да читай всё время, да еще на английском.

Comment: @manking, честно признаюсь, лень  пересказывать своими словами, например, http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Infinity-and-NaN.html

Comment: @avp
Да я уже разобрался. Единственная проблема непонятно кросс платформенное решение по выявлению inf.

Функции C++11 isinf() в VS нет. 
Есть функция _finite().
Хотя по стандарту должна быть функция std::isfinite().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно стандарту языка C++, способ представления типов с плавающей точкой (*floating-point types*) определяется реализацией. Можно воспользоваться статическим членом `is_iec559` шаблонного класса `std::numeric_limits` для проверки соответствия некоторого типа стандарту IEEE 754-2008:

```
std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559
```

Он равен `true` если тип соответствует требованиям IEEE 754-2008. Далее в ответе предполагается, что тип `double` удовлетворяет требованиям этого стандарта.

Так вот, если поделить `1.0` на `0.0`, то получится положительная бесконечность (*Infinity*). Один из возможных способов, которым реализация посредством `std::cout` может отобразить бесконечность — это `1.#INF`.

Разность двух бесконечностей с одинаковым знаком — это [`NaN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN). Один из возможных способов, которым реализация посредством `std::cout` может отобразить `NaN` — это `-1.#IND`.

1. Переменная `ind` в вашем примере равна `NaN`. `NaN` не равен ничему, включая самого себя. Вот почему выражение `ind != ind` равно `true`.
2. Конструкцию `if(ind != ind)` можно использовать для проверки на `NaN`, но не на бесконечность. Начиная с C++11, в заголовочном файле `<cmath>` есть функция `std::isnan` для проверки на `NaN` и функция `std::isinf` для проверки на бесконечность.
3. И `NaN`'ы и бесконечности хранятся в памяти также как и все остальные числа с плавающей точкой: бит знака, биты экспоненты и биты мантиссы. Если все биты экспоненты установлены в `1`, а все биты мантиссы установлены в `0`, то это бесконечность (положительная или отрицательная, в зависимости от знакового бита). Если все биты экспоненты установлены в `1`, а среди битов мантиссы есть хотя бы один не нулевой, то это `NaN`.
4. Операторы `<`, `<=`, `==`, `>=`, `>` возвращают `false` в случае, если по крайней мере один из операндов `NaN`. Поэтому все выражения `ind < 5.4`, `ind == 5.4`, `ind > 5.4` возвращают `false`. Бесконечности же сравниваются обычным образом: `−Infinity < every_finite_number < +Infinity`.

---

Стандарт языка C++ не особо требователен к типам с плавающей точкой. Многие аспекты поведения таких типов определяются реализацией. Например, стандарт IEEE 754-2008 разрешает, чтобы в случае, если один из операндов бинарного `>` — `NaN`, то генерировалось исключение.

При работе с числами с плавающей точкой, стоит помнить про возможные агрессивные оптимизации, которые компилятор может применить. Например, в Visual Studio, при использовании опции /fp:fast компилятор запросто может выражение `pinf - pinf` заменить нулём (что в случае, если `pinf` равен бесконечности или `NaN` — не верно), а выражение `ind != ind` заменить на `false` (что в случае, если `ind` равен `NaN` — не верно).